# The Google Geocoding API - INVALID_REQUEST

Tags: android, google-maps, geocoding, google-geocoding-api

I tried using The Google Geocoding API in an Android application.

When I try call this url on my browser, it works!

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=134/70%20L%C3%BD%20Ch%C3%ADnh%20Th%E1%BA%AFng%20P7%20Q3&components=country:VN&key=AIzaSyA9Vu4g-82KCt0vuFMdM5JAMuhTkxbQxp0

When I call this url in my android app, I get the response

> {"results":[],"status":"INVALID_REQUEST"}

I tried to use the Server Key or the Android key but it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you added required permission in manifest?

Comment: @user3676184 yes, i has used google geocoding api before, i has added <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

Comment: You should probably hide your API key. A bit late now, though.

Comment: What method do you use for the JSON request? You can try to use `Volley` or `okhttp` to make things more easier.